# Viewport height is not setting correctly in bxslider jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I am working on bx slider jquery plugin. Some times the viewport height is not setting correctly. this will happen when the slider is getting loaded first time. If i click the next or prev button once the viewport is set correctly.I checked in **bxSlider.js** also, it also return the wrong value.That shows that have only one children(image), but i use 5 images. I set width as 250 px but it returns 953px..The below Plugins are i used.

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.css
http://bxslider.com/js/jquery.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.js    https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/vendor/jquery.fitvids.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/vendor/jquery.easing.1.3.js

Comment: you should consider to set up a [jsfiddle.net](jsfiddle) or use the inline code editor

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: i did like a widget

Comment: if you click on save you can share it here, so you have a working demo for everyone and its more likely someone can help you ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are changes to how your page loads, say like adding an extra plugin, bxSlider will fail to finish it's calculations and it won't complete it until there's a repaint. Typically done by making the bxSlider move next or prev. I fixed this behavior by forcing bxSlider to recalculate while loading. Here's 2 suggestions, the first one is passive and minimal, the second one is aggressive and excessive. I suggest try the first one by itself and if it doesn't work, use both of them together.

**Fix #1.** Add the following ruleset to either the bottom of your stylesheet, or the last line of a `<style>` block:

```
.bx-viewport.bx-viewport { min-height: 90vh !important; }
```

This doubling up on the class selector might look odd, but it will increase the selector's selectivity, the `!important` is optional as is the double selector. This is the **Fix #1** down to it's essentials:

```
.bx-viewport { min-height: 90vh; }
```

**Fix #2.** Place this JS before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event)  {
    var $tgt = $('.bx-viewport')[0];
    var tgt = document.querySelector('.bx-viewport');
    tgt.style.height = ""
    tgt.removeAttribute('height');
    tgt.style.removeProperty('height');
    $tgt.css('height', '');
    $tgt.removeAttr('height');

}, false);
```

Most of the time using **Fix #1** will be enough. **Fix #2** is excessive but it always works.

Comment: But how to set the height based on how many slider i want to diplay?

Comment: bxSlider calculates that for you already. There is an option you can use that will determine how bxSlider handles height. By default bxSlider will find the tallest content and set all slides at that height. If you set the option: `adaptiveHeight: true` , bxSlider will adjust to the height of each slide. BTW, the 90vh can be whatever height you prefer, I use 90vh because my sliders occupy the majority of the viewport. I can't help you with specific numbers since you haven't provided any code. I'm just confident in my answer because I had the exact problem you are having now.

Comment: In the bxslider i set infinite loop as true infiniteLoop:true .i added 5 images and 2 videos. but it take many clones so sliding in not working fine. it take 2 video clone and 2 image clone.so that is not working fine.you have any solution for this problem?

Comment: That's how bxSlider handles infinite loops, unfortunately. I never use infinite loop because the clones become too heavy for the browser to process. You could set it to default then make a condition: `if(bx.getCurrentSlide ===4) {...`

Comment: If you have any trouble post a new question and I'll be over to help.

Comment: can you tell me, what are the things i need to focus to become a master in javascript?

Comment: Although I'm far from being a master at JavaScript, I can tell you how I got competent at it. I was lucky and got hired to do very simple HTML/CSS in a startup company and as the company grew, it's demands became greater, and eventually I had self-taught myself JavaScript out of necessity. My education is 80% Google and 20% college. Everyday I work and in my free time I try to learn more by helping others on SO. So whatever the company needs at the time is always my focus.

Answer (score 0):

if you try to change bxslider you see height in the following line

> in this line set height inline so you try to set your slider image height first.
>   or you can try to change using javascript